# Why .objectMap is not a function and .map is not a function?

Tags: typescript

I have a next var:

```
        const receipt = await new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) =>
          web3.eth
            .sendSignedTransaction(signTransaction.rawTransaction)
            .on('receipt', resolve)
            .on('error', reject),
        );
```

Which returns:

```
{
        "blockHash": "0x96ee...",
        "blockNumber": 16849020,
        "contractAddress": null,
        "cumulativeGasUsed": 5170728,
        "effectiveGasPrice": 19518529880,
        "from": "0x2a33a011b45aef6e9146323e9436a2b4c55a98ab",
        "gasUsed": 21000,
        "logs": [],
        "logsBloom": "0x00",
        "status": true,
        "to": "0x274e9d9bac2e7a7bcbe5ad39dccff04b02ae0deb",
        "transactionHash": "0x9c3...",
        "transactionIndex": 81,
        "type": "0x0"
}
```

But I only need certain fields, for example: `from` and `status`. For this I try to use the map or objectMap:

```
          const response = receipt.map(({from, status}) => ({
            from,
            status,
          }));
```

```
          const response = receipt.objectMap(({from, status}) => ({
            from,
            status,
          }));
```

And get errors: `receipt.map is not a function` or `receipt.objectMap is not a function`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: If `receipt.map` is not a function then `receipt` is not an array.  When you debug, what is it?  What array value were you expecting it to be?  Why?

Comment: Here receipt seems like a single object only. If that is the case, you can use object destructuring to fetch only the parameters you wish to.

Comment: @SunnyParekh can you show example?

Comment: const {from,status} = {...receipt};

console.log(from, status);

Comment: @SunnyParekh i get: `0x2a33a011b45aef6e9146323e9436a2b4c55a98ab true`

Comment: True. Cz they are the values for the keys -> from & status. Do you want the object as in {'status': true, 'from': 0x2a33a011b45aef6e9146323e9436a2b4c55a98ab}?

Comment: @SunnyParekh yes

Comment: you should use `Object.entries()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement you can use the following snippet:

```
const response = [receipt].map(({status, to}) => ({status, to}))[0];
console.log(response );
```

I hope it helps!